# launch full screen by default in code mirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I would like to launch the full screen mode of code mirror by default when I load the page.  I have the plugin installed and have the F11 keypress functions working fine.  But, is there a Javascript function I can call on the page so that the editor opens in full screen mode without the user having to place the cursor in the text area and then pressing one of the mapped keys?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like something is available: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/fullscreen/ which suggests going to http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/

Comment: thanks MonkeyZeus for the reply.  I probably wasn't very clear in my first post.  I am using this:  http://codemirror.net/demo/fullscreen.html  I've been digging for an exposed method to call the same function that is being called when F11 is mapped, but can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Sorry about that,  I can remove the comment if it is of no use to you so that future visitors don't get confused, let me know :)

Comment: nope, comment is good.  I'm sure code mirror may be using these techniques under the hood.

Comment: Co-worker showed me how to do it.   editor.setOption("fullScreen", !editor.getOption("fullScreen"));

Comment: Good stuff, it's always nice to have an idea of under-the-hood stuff. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's easier than you might think. You don't have to call a function which was mapped to F11 in the example. If it's sufficient for you to have it only in fullscreen you only need to change css to:

```
style="padding: 1px; position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: auto; height: auto; "
```

Here's a fully working example (it's like http://codemirror.net/demo/fullscreen.html but only fullscreen):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="//codemirror.net/doc/docs.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="//codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="//codemirror.net/theme/night.css">

    <script src="//codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <script src="//codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
    <script src="//codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
    <style type=text/css>
        .CodeMirror {float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>  
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding: 1px; position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: auto; height: auto; ">
        <textarea id="content" name="content" style="display: none;">&lt;dl&gt;
  &lt;dt id="option_indentWithTabs"&gt;&lt;code&gt;&lt;strong&gt;indentWithTabs&lt;/strong&gt;: boolean&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/dt&gt;
  &lt;dd&gt;Whether, when indenting, the first N*&lt;code&gt;tabSize&lt;/code&gt;
  spaces should be replaced by N tabs. Default is false.&lt;/dd&gt;

  &lt;dt id="option_electricChars"&gt;&lt;code&gt;&lt;strong&gt;electricChars&lt;/strong&gt;: boolean&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/dt&gt;
  &lt;dd&gt;Configures whether the editor should re-indent the current
  line when a character is typed that might change its proper
  indentation (only works if the mode supports indentation).
  Default is true.&lt;/dd&gt;

  &lt;dt id="option_specialChars"&gt;&lt;code&gt;&lt;strong&gt;specialChars&lt;/strong&gt;: RegExp&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/dt&gt;
  &lt;dd&gt;A regular expression used to determine which characters
  should be replaced by a
  special &lt;a href="#option_specialCharPlaceholder"&gt;placeholder&lt;/a&gt;.
  Mostly useful for non-printing special characters. The default
  is &lt;code&gt;/[\u0000-\u0019\u00ad\u200b\u2028\u2029\ufeff]/&lt;/code&gt;.&lt;/dd&gt;
  &lt;dt id="option_specialCharPlaceholder"&gt;&lt;code&gt;&lt;strong&gt;specialCharPlaceholder&lt;/strong&gt;: function(char)&nbsp;→&nbsp;Element&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/dt&gt;
  &lt;dd&gt;A function that, given a special character identified by
  the &lt;a href="#option_specialChars"&gt;&lt;code&gt;specialChars&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
  option, produces a DOM node that is used to represent the
  character. By default, a red dot (&lt;span style="color: red"&gt;•&lt;/span&gt;)
  is shown, with a title tooltip to indicate the character code.&lt;/dd&gt;

  &lt;dt id="option_rtlMoveVisually"&gt;&lt;code&gt;&lt;strong&gt;rtlMoveVisually&lt;/strong&gt;: boolean&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/dt&gt;
  &lt;dd&gt;Determines whether horizontal cursor movement through
  right-to-left (Arabic, Hebrew) text is visual (pressing the left
  arrow moves the cursor left) or logical (pressing the left arrow
  moves to the next lower index in the string, which is visually
  right in right-to-left text). The default is &lt;code&gt;false&lt;/code&gt;
  on Windows, and &lt;code&gt;true&lt;/code&gt; on other platforms.&lt;/dd&gt;
&lt;/dl&gt;
</textarea>      

    </div>
    <script>
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('content'), {
        mode: 'application/xml',
        lineNumbers: true,
        theme: "night"
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just one line :

```
 editor.setSize(window.screen.width,window.screen.height);
```